# Is a Dynamically Linked Framework possible on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

The keyword here is *possible*.  I know of a few resources that talk about this and how to create static frameworks - here: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework and here: http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/

I'm interested to see if it's *possible* to create a dynamically linked framework in an app that will not be submitted to the app store.  I know it's impossible to write to the application bundle on a device without jailbreaking it.  Is it possible to say, download a compiled framework file, put it in the documents directory and then access it via the application  (think plug-in architecture).  I know that if it is, you would be turned away from the app store for submitting it, but let's say this was an enterprise app, or an ad-hoc distributed app where Apple would not have to approve.

In my initial research I haven't found anything supporting that it is possible, but I feel like this may be such a fringe case that no one has published anything about it.  Looking for a guru to give me a definite "no" before I give up.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is what you are after but according to Apple there dynamically linked libraries even usable in iOS - for example the system libraries... XCode contains copies of them and references them via symbolic links...

see near the end of this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH6-SW3

just an idea:
put the .dylib + include files you want to use into the respective folders where XCode expects the system libraries... use themn and then put symlinks into your bundle on deployment... let the symlinks point where ou copy the .dylib

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my question properly.  I'm basically looking to make a type of plug-in architecture where I can distribute compiled code (in the form of Dynamically Linked Frameworks -- unless there is a better way) after the app has been installed on an iOS device.  I'm not looking to modify system frameworks specifically, but creating an architecture to allow expansion of the application without a user having to download a new version of the app.

Comment: I think the idea I describe can be used for such an architecture... the system frameworks location is just used as a vehicle to describe the basic pattern and how to make XCode etc. accept it... IF the idea works you could update your app by replacing a .dylib which is accessed via a symlink...

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying now (I think).  I'll see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no. Apps on the iPhone are sandboxed. That is, aside from Apple supplied frameworks, an app cannot access anything outside of its own build.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now with IOS 8 Xcode 6.